# Receiving RST_STREAM with error code 2 while using grpc secure channel

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node

We are using grpc to communicate between services. For production deployment, we switched to server authentication. We have a bi-directional streaming grpc service - which expects audio chunks in streaming fashion & sends transcripts as responses in a streaming manner. After getting the final response, we get this error:

```
13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with error code 2
```

Wasn't getting this error in case of insecure channel/no authentication. Furthermore, can't find any error on the server-side.
Using AWS grpc load balancer for server. Server code is implemented in python.
Had written a small piece of code to check if this error is encountered in the case of a python client, and we observed that this error is not seen there.

Nodejs client code for initializing the grpc client:

```
const ssl_creds = grpc.credentials.createSsl();
let client = new zapr_speech_proto.Speech(this.server_address, ssl_creds);
```

**Environment** 
OS name, version and architecture: Linux Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86-64 
Node version: v10.19.0 
Package name and version: "@grpc/grpc-js": "1.1.0", "grpc": "1.24.4"